# Transposing rows and columns

Tags: text-processing, columns

I have a file with the lines like below.

```
title1:A1
title2:A2
title3:A3
title4:A4
title5:A5

title1:B1
title2:B2
title3:B3
title4:B4
title5:B5

title1:C1
title2:C2
title3:C3
title4:C4
title5:C5

title1:D1
title2:D2
title3:D3
title4:D4
title5:D5
```

How can I achieve this?

```
title1    title2     title3    title4
A1         A2         A3         A4
B1         B2         B3         B4
C1         C2         C3         C4
D1         D2         D3         D4
```

Comment: please please please don't use awk, you might as well roll a custom solution with perl or python or a real programming language or use tr/cut with multiple passes to get what you want

Comment: Desired output posted by OP appears to be missing "title5" column.

Comment: @user79560 why? I prefer awk over all the things you said..

Answer (score 17):

Have a look at [GNU datamash](http://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) which can be used like `datamash transpose`.
A future version will also support cross tabulation (pivot tables)

Answer (score 10):

Outside of rolling a custom solution to transpose rows with columns from a command line the only tool I've ever seen that can do this is a tool called ironically [`transpose`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/transpose/).

#### Installation

Unfortunately it's not in any repo so you'll need to download and compile it. This is pretty straightforward since it has no additional libraries that it's dependent on. It can be accomplished like so:

```
$ gcc transpose.c -o transpose
```

#### Usage

It can handle straightforward text files with ease. For example:

```
$ cat simple.txt 
X column1 column2 column3
row1 0 1 2
row2 3 4 5
row3 6 7 8
row4 9 10 11
```

Can be transposed using this command:

```
$ transpose -t --fsep " " simple.txt 
X row1 row2 row3 row4
column1 0 3 6 9
column2 1 4 7 10
column3 2 5 8 11
```

This command is `transpose` to transpose (`-t`) and the field separator to use is a space (`--fsep " "`).

#### Your example

Since your sample data is in a slightly more complex format it needs to be dealt with in 2 phases. First we need to translate it into a format that `transpose` can deal with.

Running this command, will put the data in a more horizontally friendly format:

```
$ sed 's/:/ /; /^$/d' sample.txt \
    | sort | paste - - - - -
title1 A1   title1 B1   title1 C1   title1 D1   title2 A2
title2 B2   title2 C2   title2 D2   title3 A3   title3 B3
title3 C3   title3 D3   title4 A4   title4 B4   title4 C4
title4 D4   title5 A5   title5 B5   title5 C5   title5 D5
```

Now we just need to remove the secondary occurrences of the title1, title2, etc.:

```
$ sed 's/:/ /; /^$/d' sample.txt \
    | sort | paste - - - - - | sed 's/\ttitle[0-9] / /g'
title1 A1 B1 C1 D1 A2
title2 B2 C2 D2 A3 B3
title3 C3 D3 A4 B4 C4
title4 D4 A5 B5 C5 D5
```

It's now in a format that `transpose` can deal with. The following command will do the entire transposition:

```
$ sed 's/:/ /; /^$/d' sample.txt \
    | sort | paste - - - - - | sed 's/\ttitle[0-9] / /g' \
    | transpose -t --fsep " "
title1 title2 title3 title4
A1 B2 C3 D4
B1 C2 D3 A5
C1 D2 A4 B5
D1 A3 B4 C5
A2 B3 C4 D5
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a quick way to put the file into the format you want:

```
$ grep -Ev "^$|title5" sample.txt | sed 's/title[0-9]://g' | paste - - - -
A1  A2  A3  A4
B1  B2  B3  B4
C1  C2  C3  C4
D1  D2  D3  D4
```

If you want the column headers:

```
$ grep -Ev "^$|title5" sample.txt | sed 's/:.*//' | sort -u | tr '\n' '\t'; \
    echo ""; \
    grep -Ev "^$|title5" a | sed 's/title[0-9]://g' | paste - - - -
title1  title2  title3  title4  
A1      A2      A3      A4
B1      B2      B3      B4
C1      C2      C3      C4
D1      D2      D3      D4
```

#### How the 2nd command works

*printing the banner*

```
grep -Ev "^$|title5" sample.txt | sed 's/:.*//' | sort -u | tr '\n' '\t';
```

*putting a return after the banner in*

```
echo
```

*printing the rows of data*

```
grep -Ev "^$|title5" a | sed 's/title[0-9]://g' | paste - - - -
```

Comment: paste command simply made my job done. thanks for the answer...

Answer (score 8):

You could use `awk` to process the data then `paste` and `column` to format it.

Here I assume `title1` is only an example in your post, and that data does not contain `:` except as separator between header + data.

`n` signifies how many columns to print (should match dashes in `paste`).

```
awk -F":" -v n=4 \
'BEGIN { x=1; c=0;} 
 ++c <= n && x == 1 {print $1; buf = buf $2 "\n";
     if(c == n) {x = 2; printf buf} next;}
 !/./{c=0;next}
 c <=n {printf "%s\n", $2}' datafile | \
 paste - - - - | \
 column -t -s "$(printf "\t")"
```

---

If you want to make it more flexible and easy to maintain you could write it as a script. Here is an example using bash wrapper for `awk` and piped to `column`. This way you could also do more data checking like e.g. making sure headers is correct throughout all rows etc.

Used typically as:

```
$ ./trans -f data -c 4
title one  title two  title three  title four
A1         A2         A3           A4
B1         B2         B3           B4
C1         C2         C3           C4
D1         D2         D3           D4
```

If headers always is shorter then data you could also save header widths, then `printf` with `%-*s` and skip `column` all together.

```
#!/bin/bash

trans()
{
    awk -F":" -v ncol="$1" '
    BEGIN {
        level = 1 # Run-level.
        col   = 1 # Current column.
        short = 0 # If requested to many columns.
    }
    # Save headers and data for row one.
    level == 1 {
        head[col] = $1
        data[col] = $2
        if (++col > ncol) { # We have number of requested columns.
            level = 2
        } else if ($0 == "") { # If request for more columns then available.
            level = 2
            ncol  = col - 2
            short = 1
        } else {
            next
        }
    }
    # Print headers and row one.
    level == 2 {
        for (i = 1; i <= ncol; ++i)
            printf("%s\t", head[i])
        print ""
        for (i = 1; i <= ncol; ++i)
            printf("%s\t", data[i])
        level = 3
        col = ncol + 1
        if (!short)
            next
    }
    # Empty line, new row.
    ! /./ { print ""; col = 1; next }
    # Next cell.
    col > ncol {next}
    {
        printf "%s%s", $2, (col <= ncol) ? "\t" : ""
        ++col
    }
    END {print ""}
    ' "$2"
}

declare -i ncol=4  # Columns defaults to four.
file=""            # Data file (or pipe).

while [[ -n "$1" ]]; do
    case "$1" in
    "-c") ncol="$2"; shift;;
    "-f") file="$2"; shift;;
    *) printf "Usage: %s [-c <columns>] [-f <file> | pipe]\n" \
        "$(basename $0)" >&2;
        exit;;
    esac
    shift
done

trans "$ncol" "$file" | column -t -s "$(printf "\t")"
```

Comment: Nice answer! @JoelDavis and I have been hacking on this, but your answer is terrific!

Answer (score 5):

GNU datamash utility

```
apt install datamash  

datamash transpose < yourfile
```

Taken from this site, https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/ and  http://www.thelinuxrain.com/articles/transposing-rows-and-columns-3-methods

Answer (score 3):

There's probably a more succinct way of formulating this but this seems to accomplish the general effect:

```
[jadavis84@localhost ~]$ sed 's/^title[2-9]://g' file.txt | tr '\n' '\t' | sed 's/title1:/\n/g' ; echo

A1  A2  A3  A4  A5      
B1  B2  B3  B4  B5      
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5      
D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  
[jadavis84@localhost ~]$
```

Multiple `sed` invocations doesn't feel right (and I'm pretty sure sed can do the new line translation as well) so it probably isn't the most straight forward way to do it. Also, this strips the would-be headers, but you can generate those manually once you have the rows/fields formatted properly.

A better answer would probably distill that effect down to just using `sed` or `awk` to do this so that you only have one thing going on at a time. But I'm tired so this is what I was able to put together.

Comment: Joel - I made the same mistake and just noticed it, he doesn't want the title5 column in the output.

Comment: Ah, well running through awk at the last should fix that. But it looks like Sukminder's posted a complete solution.

Answer (score 3):

To balance three `awk` answers, two `datamash transpose` answers, and one `transpose` answer, here's [Miller](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference.html) in action:

```
% mlr --ixtab --ips : --opprint cat << END
title1:A1
title2:A2
title3:A3
title4:A4
title5:A5

title1:B1
title2:B2
title3:B3
title4:B4
title5:B5

title1:C1
title2:C2
title3:C3
title4:C4
title5:C5

title1:D1
title2:D2
title3:D3
title4:D4
title5:D5

END
title1 title2 title3 title4 title5
A1     A2     A3     A4     A5
B1     B2     B3     B4     B5
C1     C2     C3     C4     C5
D1     D2     D3     D4     D5
%
```

You are doing a conversion from XTAB format (`-ixtab`) to PPRINT format (`-opprint`).

If you *really do* want to eliminate `title5` (which is *not* clear from the question), then simply pre-process the input to Miller through `grep -v '^title5:'`.

Answer (score 1):

`paste` is probably your best bet. You can extract the relevant bits with `cut`, `grep` and `awk` like this:

```
(awk 'NR==1' RS= infile | cut -d: -f1; cut -sd: -f2 infile)
```

If the 5th column should be eliminated, append `awk 'NR%5'` like this:

```
(awk 'NR==1' RS= infile | cut -d: -f1; cut -sd: -f2 infile) | awk 'NR%5'
```

Now columnate with `paste`:

```
(awk 'NR==1' RS= infile | cut -d: -f1; cut -sd: -f2 infile) | awk 'NR%5' | paste - - - -
```

Output:

```
title1  title2  title3  title4
A1  A2  A3  A4
B1  B2  B3  B4
C1  C2  C3  C4
D1  D2  D3  D4
```

Answer (score 0):

For just the transpose part, I had a similar problem recently and used:

```
awk -v fmt='\t%4s'  '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ a[i]=a[i] sprintf(fmt, $i); } } END { for (i in a) print a[i]; }'
```

Adjust the fmt as needed.  For each input line, it concatenates each fields onto an array element.  Note that awk string concatenation is implicit: it happens when you write two things without any operator.

Sample I/O:

```
i       mark    accep   igna    utaal   bta
-22     -10     -10     -20     -10     -10
-21     -10     -10     -20     -10     -10
-20     -10     -10     -20     -10     -10
-19     -10     0       -10     -10     -10
-18     0       0       -10     0       0
-12     0       0       -10     0       0
-11     0       0       -10     0       0
-10     0       0       -10     0       0
```

output:

```
       i     -22     -21     -20     -19     -18     -12     -11     -10
    mark     -10     -10     -10     -10       0       0       0       0
    accep    -10     -10     -10       0       0       0       0       0
    igna     -20     -20     -20     -10     -10     -10     -10     -10
    utaal    -10     -10     -10     -10       0       0       0       0
     bta     -10     -10     -10     -10       0       0       0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

The solution is most easily accomplished by running 2 (or 3) successive one-liners on the input. The first one-liner below removes blank lines, while the second returns 5-column header-plus-data output:

```perl
raku -ne '.put if .chars;'
```

...and then:

```perl
raku -e 'my @a; @a.push( .split(":")) for lines; put [Z~] "table" xx 5, 1..5; .put for @a.map(*.[1]).rotor(5);'
```

The code above is pretty short and sweet, and can be shortened some more (for example, the statement `put [Z~] "title" xx 5, 1..5;` just recreates the Header line). Actually, the entire answer can be performed with one `raku` call as per below, which uses a ternary conditional:

```perl
raku -e 'my @a; for lines() {.chars ?? @a.push( .split(":")) !! next}; put [Z~] "title" xx 5, 1..5; .put for @a.map(*.[1]).rotor(5);'
```

To create `\t` tab-separated columns, simply `join` header and body on `\t` tab:

```
raku -e 'my @a; for lines() {.chars ?? @a.push( .split(":")) !! next}; \
         put ([Z~] "title" xx 5, 1..5).join("\t"); .put for @a.map(*.[1]).rotor(5)>>.join("\t");'
```

Sample Output:

```
title1    title2    title3    title4    title5
A1    A2    A3    A4    A5
B1    B2    B3    B4    B5
C1    C2    C3    C4    C5
D1    D2    D3    D4    D5
```

Of course, there seems to be some confusion regarding the Question because the OP omitted the last "title5" column from the desired output. That's simple enough to remedy using Raku, take the output above and run:

```perl
~$ raku -ne '.words[0..3].put;'  5columns.txt
title1    title2    title3    title4 
A1    A2    A3    A4 
B1    B2    B3    B4 
C1    C2    C3    C4 
D1    D2    D3    D4
```

https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

In this code file1 is the input table with blanks removed.

We first "reduce" and sort file1:

```
$ awk -F":" '{a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2} END {for (i in a) print i  a[i]}' table1 | sort 
title1 A1 B1 C1 D1
title2 A2 B2 C2 D2
title3 A3 B3 C3 D3
title4 A4 B4 C4 D4
title5 A5 B5 C5 D5
```

Transpose this with tab-separated output is trivial:

```
$ awk '{{OFS="\t"} for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i]= (i in a?a[i] OFS :"") $i; } 
    END{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print a[i] } $1'

title1  title2  title3  title4  title5
A1      A2      A3      A4      A5
B1      B2      B3      B4      B5
C1      C2      C3      C4      C5
D1      D2      D3      D4      D5
```