# shell or python script to transpose rows to columns

Tags: shell-script, scripting, python

I have a big file with numbers like:

```
 1 2 3 4
 5 6 7 8
 9 9 9 9
```

I want to tranpose it into

```
 1 5 9
 2 6 9
 3 7 9
 4 8 9
```

I have search on google for solutions, 
but those solutions simply don't work in my case.

Comment: Try http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79642/9537, and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1729824/855954

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution should work for you.

```
awk '
{ 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  {
        a[NR,i] = $i
    }
}
NF>p { p = NF }
END {    
    for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
        str=a[1,j]
        for(i=2; i<=NR; i++){
            str=str" "a[i,j];
        }
        print str
    }
}' file
```

**TESTING**

```
cat file

1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 0 1 11
```

After running the above command, the output is,

```
1 5 9
2 6 0
3 7 1
4 8 11
```

**REFERENCES**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/transpose-a-file-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `perl`:

```
$ perl -anle '
    $l[$_] .= $F[$_] for 0..$#F;
    END {
        print join " ", split // for @l;
    }' file
1 5 9
2 6 9
3 7 9
4 8 9
```

or using `unpack`:

```
$ perl -nle '
    $i = 0;
    $l[$i++] .= $_ for unpack "(A2)*";
    END {
        print join " ", split // for @l;
    }' file
1 5 9
2 6 9
3 7 9
4 8 9
```