# How to use awk or sed to convert rows to columns

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I need to transpose a file.

Input file:

```
1/1/1111
1
2
3
4

2/2/2222
5
6
7
8
```

Output:

```
1/1/1111 1 2 3 4
2/2/2222 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: Try: http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=transpose

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transposing rows and columns](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79642/transposing-rows-and-columns)

Comment: is it always a header line followed by 4 data lines and a blank line as separator, or is the format (e.g. the number of data lines) varying in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed -e '
  :1
  $!N
  /\n$/{
    P
    d
  }
  s/\n/ /
  t1
' <file
```

Answer (score 4):

what about xargs

```
 xargs -n5 < input_file
```

or awk

```
awk '{a=(NR%6==0)?"":a$0" ";if(NR%6==5)print a}' inp
```

Comment: Both methods assume a fixed number of entries per "column" which the OP doesn't explicitly specify.

Comment: yes right. Still working on that.

Answer (score 3):

In `perl`

```
perl -lp00e 's/\n/ /g' your_file
```

**Explanation**

- `l`: Remove the input record separator from the current record being processed and add the current output record separator (a newline by default) after each printed line.
- `-p`: Operate on the file record by record and print the current record after processing.
- `-00`: Means the record separator is two or more **consecutive** newlines
- `-e` : execute the following string as code while setting the default variable (`$_`) to the record currently being read from the file.
- `s/\n/ /g`: Replace every newline encountered in the current record with a space (the `g` modifier ensures the replacement is "global").

Comment: `perl -lp00e 's/\n/ /g'` is shorter and work with old perl.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{ORS=" ";}; !NF{ORS="\n"};1' file
```

The `ORS` variable specifies the [output record separator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Output-Separators.html). If the number of fields is zero (the line is empty) then the record separator should be a newline, else a space. The `1` at the end just means a positive condition, so `awk` prints the whole line.

Comment: This will remove the last newline of file, and also doesn't work if line contain `0`.

Comment: @cuonglm Thanks for the note, now it works also with a 0.

Answer (score 2):

are they all the same format, i.e. 6 lines for each block? if so, `paste` is simplest (that is 6 dashes):

```
paste - - - - - - < file
```

If you need spaces rather than tabs, add `-d' '`