# awk + how to append list in file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have the following list in file

more file.ex

```
efifc1a
hygg4a
hdy5d


nhdw4s
wesf3a
fjfhyr



jfhg
gsfar
```

how to append any second list after the first list and any third list after the second list the following:

```
efifc1a   nhdw4s     jfhg
hygg4a    wesf3a     gsfar
hdy5d     fjfhyr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
awk '
  BEGIN {FS="\n"; RS="\n\n+"}
  {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i] = a[i] == ""? $i : a[i]"\t"$i; next}
  END {for (i in a) print a[i]}
' file.ex
```

Testing:

```
awk '
>   BEGIN {FS="\n"; RS="\n\n+"}
>   {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i] = a[i] == ""? $i : a[i]"\t"$i; next}
>   END {for (i in a) print a[i]}
> ' file.ex
efifc1a nhdw4s  jfhg
hygg4a  wesf3a  gsfar
hdy5d   fjfhyr
```

If you're not stuck on using awk, you could do it using [autogen's `columns` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/manual/html_node/columns-Invocation.html) and the `transpose` command described here [Transposing rows and columns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88179/65304) e.g.

```
columns -c3 < file.ex | tr -s ' ' '\t' | transpose -t
```

Comment: Standard `awk` iterates `for (i in a)` in **indeterminate order**; for the gawk's I have numbers up to 3 (your test case) happen to work but more don't; oh Ubuntu `mawk` up to 9 works, but on FreeBSD `awk` even 2 fails, and I no longer have Solaris. *Recent GNU* awk can fix this with [`PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning) but anywhere and easier you can use `for(i = 1; i in a; i++) print a[i]`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 good info, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you accept having temporary files, you could do it as a two step process with `awk` and `paste`:

```
n=$(awk '{ print $0 > NR; close(NR) } END { print NR }' RS= file.ex)
paste $(seq $n)
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
paste $(seq $(awk '{ print $0 > NR; close(NR) } END { print NR }' RS= file.ex))
```

Output in both cases:

```
efifc1a nhdw4s  jfhg
hygg4a  wesf3a  gsfar
hdy5d   fjfhyr
```

Note, this creates numbered files in the current directory, so take care not to overwrite other files.