# Converting grep output from row format to column format in pipe

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

I am using a program called "dsk" to run analyses. I am interested in only a few lines of the analyses, and am using the following to retrieve those lines:

```
dsk -file <filename> | grep -Ei 'string1|string2|string3'
```

which gives me something like:

```
string1                                : 13
string2                                : 46
string3                                : 39
```

*Edit: Reformatted to be more  true to output (not tab limited, with 32 spaces, a colon, and another space in between fields)

However, I would like the output to look something like this:

```
string1 string2 string3
13      46      39
```

The answer Glenn provided generates the following, likely because the spaces are causing confusion:

```
string1 string2 string3
:   :   :
```

Comment: Related: [Transposing rows and columns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79642/transposing-rows-and-columns)

Answer (score 1):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) instead of [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)

```
dsk -file "$file" | awk '
    tolower($1) ~ /string1|string2|string3/ { n++; vars[n] = $1; vals[n] = $2 }
    END {
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) printf "%s\t", vars[i]
        print ""
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) printf "%s\t", vals[i]
        print ""
    }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

The general-purpose tools mentioned in the answer linked by @SteelDriver are highly suitable, as is @glenn jackman's answer.

However, if your data is formatted as simply as you indicate --  that is, if there are no spaces in the `string1 .. stringN` pieces -- then at the expense of reading your input file twice, you can also do this:

```
dsk -file <filename> | grep -Ei 'string1|string2|string3' > tempfile.txt

readarray labels < <(awk '{print $1}' tempfile.txt)
readarray values < <(awk '{print $2}' tempfile.txt)

printf '%s\t' ${labels[@]}
printf '\n'

printf '%s\t' ${values[@]}
printf '\n'
```

That formatting may be somewhat simplistic, and in particular might not align the entries as nicely as you might like.  But if all you need is tab-delimited output, it will do that.