putting each character of multiple lines into a register corresponding to its relative position in the line
Awkard way to pharse it in the title ik. I'll break it down better so that it makes sense. I have a file that says:
abab
baaa
babb

I need to read each character of a line into a register corresponding to its position in the line. So, starting with the first line, "abab"

"a" goes to register 1,
"b" goes to register 2,
"a" goes to register 3,
"b" goes to register 4 and so on.

Now for the second line, "baaa",

"b" gets appended to register 1,
"a" gets appended to register 2.
"a" is appended to register 3 and
"a" is appended to register 4.

Doing that for all lines gives me four registers, corresponding to each character position.

abb
baa
aab
bab

Another thing worth noting is that I want to do that for multiple files with similar contents, so that in the end I have a register containing all the characters of the first position on the line, another with all the characters of the second position of the line and so on.

1 abbababbab.....
2 baababbabaa...
...
n babbabaaaaba...

can i do this in shell script or do I need dabble into some awking for that

What does "register" mean in this context? Aside from that, it sounds like you are asking How to transpose a text file on character basis

Could be something like perl -F// -lane 'my $i; $reg[$i++] .= $_ for @F; END{print for @reg}' file1 file2...

You CAN do it in a shell script but you SHOULD dabble in some awking for that. A shell is not a tool to manipulate text (which is what you're doing) while awk  is such a tool so an awk script will be briefer, simpler, more portable and faster than a shell script for this.

The register comes to mind is vim's register :-)

Assumptions:

'register' can be represented by an array
register[X] contains a concatenated strings of characters from the Xth character of an input line

Setup:
$ cat file1
abab
baaa
babb

$ cat file2
1234no
5678pq
90_%#?
WXYZ

NOTE: it's not clear from OP's description of all files have the same number of lines with all lines having the same length so file2 may not be valid; regardless, each character should be appended to the corresponding register[]
One idea using bash:
register=()

for fname in file[12]
do
    while read -r line
    do
        for ((i=0; i<${#line}; i++))
        do
            register[$i+1]+="${line:i:1}"
        done
    done < "${fname}"
done

typeset -p register

This generates:
declare -a register=([1]="abb159W" [2]="baa260X" [3]="aab37_Y" [4]="bab48%Z" [5]="np#" [6]="oq?")

A bash solution is going to be relatively slow, while better performance could be had with a tool built for file and string processing (eg, awk, perl, python, ruby, etc).
Doing the same thing in awk:
awk '
    { len = length($0)
      for (i=1; i<=len; i++)
          register[i] = register[i] substr($0,i,1)
      max_i = len > max_i ? len : max_i
    }
END { for (i=1; i<=max_i; i++)
          printf "register[%d]=%s\n", i, register[i]
    }
' file[12]

This generates:
register[1]=abb159W
register[2]=baa260X
register[3]=aab37_Y
register[4]=bab48%Z
register[5]=np#
register[6]=oq?

NOTE: it's not clear from OP's description if/how these 'registers' are to be used in follow-on programming; obviously if the 'registers' are to be used outside of awk then it will be necessary to capture the awk output into a form that can be used by follow-on programming; I'll leave that up to OP to figure out, or to ask in a separate question

Without IFS= in the while read the bash script will strip leading/trailing spaces from each line which may not be desirable.

Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)
Assuming "ragged-array", i.e. unequal number of elements per row:
~$ raku -e 'my @F = lines; 
            my @reg = roundrobin(@F.map(*.comb)); 
            .join.put for @reg;'  file

#OR

~$ raku -e 'my @F = lines.map: *.comb(/./); 
            my my $max1 = @F.map(*.elems).max; my @reg;
            for ^$max1 -> $i { 
                for @F[$i].kv -> $k,$v { 
                    @reg[$k].push: $v 
                }
            }; .join.put for @reg;'   file

Above is an answer coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. The code above splits text into individual characters using .comb (either .comb(/./) or .split("", :skip-empty) also work). In the first example Raku's roundrobin() method is used.
In the second example the code basically runs 2 for loops over the input text in order to push transposed characters onto the @reg array. Here Raku conveniently offers the .kv routine, which (when run over array-elements) provides the element index position as key and the element text as value.
Note above, if you want to insert a "placeholder" for uneven rows, see:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/690426/227738
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/782211/227738

Assuming equal number of elements per row:
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my @reg; 
             @reg.push: $_.split("", :skip-empty); 
             END .join.put for [Z] @reg;'  file

#OR

~$ raku  -e 'my @reg; for lines() { 
             @reg.push: $_.split("", :skip-empty) }; 
             .join.put for [Z] @reg;'  file

The problem simplifies greatly if you can be assured of equal elements per row. Here Raku's [Z] reduction metaoperator "zips" together elements at the same index position (however should unequal-elements-per-row exist they will get dropped in the output).
Sample Input:
abab
baaax
babb

Sample Output 1 (first code-block that assumes unequal rows):
abb
baa
aab
bab
x

Sample Output 2 (second code-block that assumes equal rows):
abb
baa
aab
bab

https://docs.raku.org/routine/roundrobin
https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Reduction_metaoperators
https://raku.org
